# How to specify volume host path in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, path, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to share a volume among multiple containers, and specify the path for this volume on the host.

I used the following settings:

```
version: '3'
services:
    service1:
        image: image1
        volumes:
            - volume1:/volume1
    service2:
        image: image2
        volumes:
            - volume1:/volume1
volumes:
  volume1:
    driver: local                 # meaning?
    driver_opts:
      o: bind                     # meaning?
      type: none                  # meaning?
      device: /volume1            # the path on the host
```

But I am not sure of the `driver: local`, `type: none` and `o: bind` options.

I would like to have a regular volume (like without specifying any `driver` nor `driver_opts`), just being able to specify the path on the host.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). Specifying the `volumes` key means that you're creating a volume in the Docker machine for persistent storage. Despite the name, a `volume` is not necessarily related to `volumes`.

Use something like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    image: image1
    volumes:
      - type: bind # Host and Docker machines have identical views to the same directory; changes propagate both ways
        source: . # Host machine directory to mount
        target: /app # Docker machine directory to be mapped to
```